# filter a list using another list of objects

Tags: bash

How I can filter a file (list2.txt) using another list (list1.txt)?

For example

`list1.txt`:

```
AAA
002
```

`list2.txt`:

```
treu____ DDD
tryu____ EEE
657r____ 002
25oi____ AAA
ytry____ TRE
tr35____ AAA
kgir____ IUY
```

`output.txt`:

```
657r____ 002
25oi____ AAA
tr35____ AAA
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: You can use `grep`

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the programming language. I have to do this mandatory step but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the man-page for _grep_. Perhaps something like `grep -wF -f list1.txt list2.txt` will do the job. Whether or not `-w` is appropriate in your case, is something only you can decide.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the man-page for *grep*. Perhaps something like

```
grep -wF -f list1.txt list2.txt
```

will do the job. Whether or not `-w` is appropriate in your case, is something only you can decide.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next} ($2 in arr)' list1.txt list2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{               ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when list1.txt is being read.
  arr[$1]              ##Creating arr with index as 1st field on current line.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($2 in arr)            ##Checking condition if 2nd field is present in arr then print that line from list2.txt
' list1.txt list2.txt  ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=1;next } map[$2]==1 { print }' list1.txt list2.txt
```

Process the first file (NR==FNR) and set up an array called map with the first tab separated field as the index and skip to the next line. Then for the second file, check if there is an entry for the second tab delimited field in the array and if there is, print the line

Comment: 2 comments:
The first is that in the file list2.txt the first and second columns are separated by TAB and not by space. The second is that in order to filter the file2 I have to use only the object in the second column without considering the names present in the first one because some of them include the codes of the file list1.

Comment: No worries, I've changed the awk solution